# Coulomb excitation of a heavy nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, doppler-effect

In Coulomb excitation measurements involving a stationary target getting excited, why do the de-excitation $\gamma$-rays get Doppler shifted and Doppler broadened as well? How can these be corrected to obtain precise results?

Comment: Can you provide a reference? The first thing that comes to mind is thermal motion, but that's pretty small from the perspective of nuclear spectroscopy.

Comment: @rob it is Doppler broadening but not due to thermal motion. It is because "the recoil velocities of the excited target nuclei can be large" p690 http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~cline/Publications/annurev.ns.36.120186.pdf.

Comment: These are mentioned in an article on Coulex by D. Cline (the one linked to in the comment above). What leads to the Doppler shift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excited nuclei don't get that way on their own: you have to hit them with a beam.  [Your reference](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~cline/Publications/annurev.ns.36.120186.pdf) starting on page 689, refers to beams of oxygen, silicon, calcium, and nickel, with energies of several MeV per nucleon, on stationary lead targets.  Pick a target, beam, beam energy, and reasonable excitation energies for the target and beam nucleus, then use conservation of energy and momentum to find the recoil of the target nucleus after the collision; you'll find that it's quite substantial.

Comment: thanks. this explains the broadening? But what about the Doppler shift? Is it due to difference in the frames of reference?

Comment: The Doppler shift will come about because the center-of-momentum for the colliding system is different from the rest frame of the detector; the broadening is because the direction of the fragments in the c.o.m. frame is random.